# How to use a whole new set of assets (reskinning)

Tags: unity, assets

I need to be able to load my game with a different set of assets, basically reskinning it.

I knew beforehand that I would need a way to do that in the future so right now i'm accessing my assets via a ScriptableObject that I call an "Accessor".

Basically the accessor only hold references to the assets and when I want to get, for example, the sprite for my cards I make a call that looks like that :

```
Sprite cardSprite = Accessors.Instance.GetCardFrame();
```

Solution seem simple, I add a layer above the accessors that allow it to choose between differents sets of references.

The problem is that right now I only use the accessors for dynamically generated gameobject ( When I instantiate a card for exemple ). How could I do that with, let's say, UI in the editor ? It will be nearly impossible to work on the UI if I can't see it due to the sprite not being loaded in editor mode.

Comment: This sounds like a subject [Asset Bundle Variants](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager) may be able to help with, though I don't have enough experience with them myself to offer a full solution.

Comment: @DMGregory I knew about Asset Bundle but not about Asset Bundle Variants. I will have a look into it and post an answer if it solves my problem.